# Custom filtering on Jquery Data table and reassigning AjaxSource

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datatables

My application is in Asp.net MVC3, i have added Jquery Datatable, it works fine on default load. But I want to add custom filtering to the Index page on which the data-table is implemented.
Below is the sample code, but this is exactly how I implement my index View with Data-table.

```
  var oTable1 = $('.My_Table_Class').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/CityMaster/AjaxCityFill",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sScrollY": "300px",
            aaSorting: [[0, 'desc']],
            "b$UI": true,
            "bAutoWidth": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "sDom": '<"dtShowPer"l><"dtFilter"f><"#dataTables_filter_search_button"><"dtInfo"i><"dtPagination"p><"dtTables">rt<"dtInfo"i><"dtPagination"p><"F">',
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
                "sZeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
                "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ records",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 records",
                "sInfoFiltered": ""
            }
        });
```

The Above method will get the data from query like this

```
"Select * from CityMaster"
```

There will be selection filter above the Index View like CountryName, CityName, CountryCode
What i want to achieve is:

1. I want to reassign url to **sAjaxSource** which will get the data from a method that will accept parameters like "CountryName" , "CityName"
   like this

   ```
   sAjaxSource": "/CityMaster/AjaxCityFillWithFilter?CountryName=India&CityName=Maharashtra,
   ```

Below are the things that i have tried

```
 1. var oSettings = oTable1.fnSettings();
    oSettings.sAjaxSource  = "/CityMaster/AjaxCityFillWithFilter?  CountryName=India&CityName=Maharashtra;

 2. oTable1.ajax.url("/CityMaster/AjaxCityFillWithFilter?        CountryName=India&CityName=Maharashtra).load();
```

**None of the above methods are working.**

***Updates***
After implementing the below answer provided by @EuphoriaGrogi , following are the errors im getting
1.[image: When i add As DataTable i get this error]

[image: so i change it to dataTable and again i get the error that .draw is not a function]

Comment: Have a look at this: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

Comment: you can try my yadcf plugin for that, see showcase sample http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html

Answer (score 0):

there is a property in datatable wherein you can specify your filters `fnServerParams` :

```
"fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
      aoData.push({ "name": "sBookTitle", "value": $("#Book_Title").val() });
      aoData.push({ "name": "sAuthor", "value": $("#Author").val() });
 },
```

Assuming that you have a `Search` button that will trigger the searching in the event listener just redraw the table like this.

```
$("#searchBtn").on("click", function () {
        var bookResultsTable = $('#bookResultsTable').DataTable();
        bookResultsTable.draw();
    });
```

This will automatically call the ajax source passing the value of the filters.

In my controller you can retrieve the value of the filters in request parameters.

```
    public ActionResult BookListHandler(JQueryDataTableParamModel param , FormCollection values)
    {
        var filterBookTitle = Request.Params[Constants.Book_Title_Param].Trim() ?? string.Empty;
        var filterAuthor = Request.Params[Constants.Author_Param].Trim() ?? string.Empty;
        ... // rest of code here
    }
```

Comment: please check the updates of my Question, i had defined $("#MyTable").DataTable -- it gave the error The i changed it to $("#MyTable").dataTable but bookResultsTable.draw(); gave error that .draw is not a method –

Comment: @SamM what is the version of your datatable?